# How to understand the ingredient of this sentence？

Tags: relative-clauses, clauses, subordinate-clauses, dependent-clause

I saw this sentence from the internet,

> The input to this transformer should be an array-like of integers or strings, denoting the values taken on by categorical (discrete) features

I can not understand the second part of the sentence. What's the function of the word 'taken on'? How to analyze the ingredient of this sentence?

Comment: Taken, assumed, no doubt shown.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Could you explain it in detail? Thank you.

Comment: I'm wondering what an "array-like" is.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  Are you certain you have copied this text properly - it doesn't seem correct. Please can you give a link to this text so that we can see the context. Thanks.

Comment: A glance at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html shows this to be a sample of very specialised software text dealing with the manipulation of arrays of features within a database. The understanding of this follows not from English usage but from  knowledge of the conventions and methods of the software and its algorithms. The question is not suited to this site and I am voting to close it.

Comment: [Macmillan sense 2](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/take-on) for the transitive multi-word verb _take on_.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it relates to specialised algorithms and esoteric software conventions, and not to English usage.

Comment: @HotLicks Like a vector, a sequence.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica Thank you! The link is https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

Comment: @jie - But how is "array-like" a noun?

Comment: @HotLicks I don't know. I can not really understand the structure of the sentence.

Comment: @Jie - That's because it's very poorly written.

Comment: @HotLicks Thank you for your comment. I was wondering if I misunderstand the meaning. If you also think the grammar is not that right, I will just ignore this e-book.

Comment: @HotLicks It's very much a "programmer's sentence"... Many computer programming languages have a concept of an _array_ – a sequence of values that can be referred-to collectively (`myArray`) or accessed individually (`myArray[0]`, `myArray[1]` etc.). _Some_ languages have things that aren't _really_ arrays, but have some _array-like_ properties. The function (="transformer") in question presumably accepts either a real array, or an object/variable with array-like properties. I agree that "_array-like object_" or "_...parameter_" would be better wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe my computer science background can help - I don't have any experience working with transformers but this verbiage is similar to my trade.

To me this feels like it's missing a word and wasn't proofread for clarity. I would assume it should be rephrased as follows:

> The input to this transformer should be an array-like **series** of integers or strings<strike>, denoting</strike> that represent the values <strike>taken on by</strike> **of** categorical (discrete) features

I do not know exactly what these "categorical features" are, but the use of "discrete" implies that they are unique. My best guess is that the array-like input maps to an analogous array of categories, and each entry controls a particular feature.

Comment: Thank you for your help!